# Regular expression to confirm whether a string is a valid Python identifier?

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, identifier

I have the following definition for an Identifier:

```
Identifier --> letter{ letter| digit}
```

Basically I have an identifier function  that  gets a string from a file and tests it to make sure that it's a valid identifier as defined above.

I've tried this:

```
if re.match('\w+(\w\d)?', i):     
  return True
else:
  return False
```

but when I run my  program every time it meets an integer it  thinks that  it's a valid identifier.

For example

```
c = 0 ;
```

it  prints `c` as a valid identifier which is fine, but it also prints `0` as a valid identifer.

What  am I doing  wrong here?

Comment: You know your definition isn't the same as Python's, right? Python allows underscores too.

Comment: All of the regex answers are not quite right, [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059733/3346095Z).

Answer (score 30):

Question was made 10 years ago, when Python 2 was still dominant. As many comments in the last decade demonstrated, my answer needed a serious update, starting with a big heads up:

***No simple regex will properly match all (and only) valid Python identifiers. It didn't for Python 2, it doesn't for Python 3.***

The reasons are:

- As JoeCondron [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474008/regular-expression-to-confirm-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-python-identifier#comment62879732_10134719), Python reserved keywords such as `True`, `if`, `return` are **not** valid identifiers, so simple regexes alone are unable to handle this and additional filtering is required.
- Python 3 allows non-ASCII letters and numbers in an identifier, but the Unicode categories of letters and numbers accepted by the lexical parser for a valid identifier **do not match** the same categories of `\d`, `\w`, `\W` in the `re` module, as demonstrated in martineau's [counter-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474008/regular-expression-to-confirm-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-python-identifier/54059733#comment88870337_10134719) and explained in great detail by Hatshepsut's [amazing research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059733/624066).

We *could* try to solve the first issue either by using [`keyword.iskeyword()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.iskeyword) as Alexander Huszagh [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474008/regular-expression-to-confirm-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-python-identifier/54059733#comment83063405_10134719), or by listing *all* keywords in a (huge) regex negative lookahead clause as [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474008/regular-expression-to-confirm-whether-a-string-is-a-valid-python-identifier/54059733#comment137392401_10134719) by Feuermurmel. And we can workaround the other issue by restricting ourselves to ASCII-only identifiers.

But, with all this trouble and limitations, why bother using a regex *at all*?

As Hatshepsut said:

> **[`str.isidentifier()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier)** works

***Just use it, problem solved.***

<sup>*PS: If you upvote me just for this, please also upvote the [answer that originally posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059733/624066) this solution!*</sup>

---

As requested by the question, my original 2012 answer presents a regular expression based on the [Python 2 official definition of an identifier](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

```bnf
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

Which can be expressed by the regular expression:

```
^[^\d\W]\w*\Z
```

Example:

```python
import re
identifier = re.compile(r"^[^\d\W]\w*\Z", re.UNICODE)

tests = [ "a", "a1", "_a1", "1a", "aa$%@%", "aa bb", "aa_bb", "aa\n", "if" ]
for test in tests:
    result = re.match(identifier, test)
    print("%r\t= %s" % (test, (result is not None)))
```

Result:

```
'a'      = True
'a1'     = True
'_a1'    = True
'1a'     = False
'aa$%@%' = False
'aa bb'  = False
'aa_bb'  = True
'aa\n'   = False
'if'     = True
```

And remember to use `keyword.iskeyword()` to avoid false positives such as the last one.

Comment: I might be worth mentioning that this matches kewords such as `True`, `return` etc. I'm not suggesting a change to the regex but just that the OP might want to bear that in mind.

Comment: @JoeCondron This is also very easy to do, since Python contains the `keyword.iskeyword` function, which is merely a wrapper around the keyword list frozenset.

Comment: In Python 3.6 at least, this doesn't work for the Unicode string `'℘᧚'` even though that **is** a valid identifier in Python 3 (and isn't a keyword).

Comment: Your first reason given is definitely wrong. You can exclude keywords using negative lookahead along the lines of `re.fullmatch(r'(?!(True|False|if|else|...)\b)...')`, replacing `\b` with an word boundary definition that matches Python's identifiers.

Comment: @Feuermurmel: I stand corrected, and edited my answer to mention your solution.

Answer (score 15):

**[`str.isidentifier()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier)** works. The regex answers incorrectly fail to match some valid python identifiers and incorrectly match some invalid ones.

> `str.isidentifier()` Return true if the string is a valid identifier
>   according to the language definition, section Identifiers and
>   keywords.
>
> Use `keyword.iskeyword()` to test for reserved identifiers such as def
>   and class.

@martineau's comment gives the example of `'℘᧚'` where the regex solutions fail.

```
>>> '℘᧚'.isidentifier()
True
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.search(r'^[^\d\W]\w*\Z', '℘᧚'))
False
```

#### Why does this happen?

Lets define the sets of code points that match the given regular expression, and the set that match `str.isidentifier`.

```
import re
import unicodedata

chars = {chr(i) for i in range(0x10ffff) if re.fullmatch(r'^[^\d\W]\w*\Z', chr(i))}
identifiers = {chr(i) for i in range(0x10ffff) if chr(i).isidentifier()}
```

How many regex matches are not identifiers?

```
In [26]: len(chars - identifiers)                                                                                                               
Out[26]: 698
```

How many identifiers are not regex matches?

```
In [27]: len(identifiers - chars)                                                                                                               
Out[27]: 4
```

Interesting -- which ones?

```
In [37]: {(c, unicodedata.name(c), unicodedata.category(c)) for c in identifiers - chars}                                                       
Out[37]: 
set([
    ('\u1885', 'MONGOLIAN LETTER ALI GALI BALUDA', 'Mn'),
    ('\u1886', 'MONGOLIAN LETTER ALI GALI THREE BALUDA', 'Mn'),
    ('℘', 'SCRIPT CAPITAL P', 'Sm'),
    ('℮', 'ESTIMATED SYMBOL', 'So'),
])
```

#### What's different about these two sets?

They have different Unicode "General Category" values.

```
In [31]: {unicodedata.category(c) for c in chars - identifiers}                                                                                 
Out[31]: set(['Lm', 'Lo', 'No'])
```

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category), that's `Letter, modifier`; `Letter, other`; `Number, other`. This is consistent with the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), since `\d` is only decimal digits:

> `\d` Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category [Nd])

What about the other way?

```
In [32]: {unicodedata.category(c) for c in identifiers - chars}                                                                                 
Out[32]: set(['Mn', 'Sm', 'So'])
```

That's `Mark, nonspacing`; `Symbol, math`; `Symbol, other`.

#### Where is this all documented?

- In the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)
- In [PEP 3131 - Supporting non-ascii identifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/)

#### Where is it implemented?

https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/47383403a0a11259acb640406a8efc38981d2255

#### I still want a regular expression

Look at the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module on PyPI.

> This regex implementation is backwards-compatible with the standard ‘re’ module, but offers additional functionality.

It includes filters for "General Category".

Comment: Can you provide an example of when this works but the regex(es) fail?

Comment: Indeed, you're right — but that surprises me because the `re` documentation seems to indicate that it support Unicode strings (even without a `re.UNICODE` flag in Python 3.x).

Comment: @martineau Out of curiosity, how did you run across that particular one?

Comment: I was developing a regex to recognize Python "special" method names i.e those start and end with two underscore characters. `__` — aka "dunder" names, so was searching this site for a general one that recognized any valid identifier. Guess, I'll have to give-up on doing it with an `re` regex...in fact, I now suspect the module's limitation/bug may be why the string`isidentifier` method was added in Python 3.

Comment: ...following on after your recent update: Yes, I'm aware there are third-party regex libraries, but would prefer to limit what I'm doing to the standard library — and so will use a combination of `str.isidentifer()` along with `str.startswith()` & `str.endswith()` to detect dunder names (the code not being especially speed critical). Thank you for the responses (and answer updates).

Comment: What an amazing research and answer! Made me completely revamp my own.I wasn't aware of `str.isidentifier()`, not sure if it was available in 2012. But in 2021 it really makes no sense using a regex at all.

Answer (score 3):

For Python 3, you need to handle Unicode letters and digits. So if that's a concern, you should get along with this:

```
re_ident = re.compile(r"^[^\d\W]\w*$", re.UNICODE)
```

`[^\d\W]` matches a character that is not a digit and not "not alphanumeric" which translates to "a character that is a letter or underscore".

Comment: Almost there... but not quite... it will fail for single-letter identifiers "a", and it also allows "aa@#$%" as a valid identifier

Answer (score 2):

\w matches digits and characters. Try `^[_a-zA-Z]\w*$`

Comment: Careful, Python 3 allows all Unicode letters and digits in its identifiers.

Comment: Should it be "[_a-zA-Z]\w*" since you want to match 0 or more after the initial character?

Comment: That will match "a$%@#%" as a valid identifier

Answer (score 0):

<sup>The question is about regex, so my answer may look out of subject. The point is that regex is simply not the right approach.</sup>

***Interested in getting the problematic characters ?***

Using [`str.isidentifier`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isidentifier.asp), one can perform the check character by character, prefixing them with, say, an underscore to avoid false positive such as digits and so on... How could a name be valid if one of its (prefixed) component is not (?) E.g.

```
def checker(str_: str) -> 'set[str]':
    return {
        c for i, c in enumerate(str_)
        if not (f'_{c}' if i else c).isidentifier()
    }
```

```
>>> checker('℘3᧚₂')
{'₂'}
```

Which solution deals with unauthorised first characters, such as digits or e.g. `᧚`. See

```
>>> checker('᧚℘3₂')
{'₂', '᧚'}
>>> checker('3᧚℘₂')
{'3', '₂'}
>>> checker("a$%@#%\n")
{'@', '#', '\n', '$', '%'}
```

To be improved, since it does check neither for reserved names, nor tells anything about why `᧚` is sometime problematic, whereas `₂` always is... but here is my without-regex approach.

---

*My* answer in *your* terms:

```
if not checker(i):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

which could be contracted into

```
return not checker(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a working regex (i.e. I couldn't just use `str.isidentifier`) because I needed to find all identifiers embedded in a string, not just test if a whole string was a valid identifier. I also couldn't use the `ast` module because I expected the string to not be valid Python syntax. So the existing answers didn't help, and I wasn't satisfied with 'use the regex package'. So here's an actual regex that does the job, along with the code for constructing it and testing it.

```py
# coding: utf-8
import itertools
import re

full_pattern = r"[A-Z_a-zªµºÀ-ÖØ-öø-ˁˆ-ˑˠ-ˤˬˮͰ-ʹͶ-ͷͻ-ͽͿΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΡΣ-ϵϷ-ҁҊ-ԯԱ-Ֆՙՠ-ֈא-תׯ-ײؠ-يٮ-ٯٱ-ۓەۥ-ۦۮ-ۯۺ-ۼۿܐܒ-ܯݍ-ޥޱߊ-ߪߴ-ߵߺࠀ-ࠕࠚࠤࠨࡀ-ࡘࡠ-ࡪࢠ-ࢴࢶ-ࣇऄ-हऽॐक़-ॡॱ-ঀঅ-ঌএ-ঐও-নপ-রলশ-হঽৎড়-ঢ়য়-ৡৰ-ৱৼਅ-ਊਏ-ਐਓ-ਨਪ-ਰਲ-ਲ਼ਵ-ਸ਼ਸ-ਹਖ਼-ੜਫ਼ੲ-ੴઅ-ઍએ-ઑઓ-નપ-રલ-ળવ-હઽૐૠ-ૡૹଅ-ଌଏ-ଐଓ-ନପ-ରଲ-ଳଵ-ହଽଡ଼-ଢ଼ୟ-ୡୱஃஅ-ஊஎ-ஐஒ-கங-சஜஞ-டண-தந-பம-ஹௐఅ-ఌఎ-ఐఒ-నప-హఽౘ-ౚౠ-ౡಀಅ-ಌಎ-ಐಒ-ನಪ-ಳವ-ಹಽೞೠ-ೡೱ-ೲഄ-ഌഎ-ഐഒ-ഺഽൎൔ-ൖൟ-ൡൺ-ൿඅ-ඖක-නඳ-රලව-ෆก-ะาเ-ๆກ-ຂຄຆ-ຊຌ-ຣລວ-ະາຽເ-ໄໆໜ-ໟༀཀ-ཇཉ-ཬྈ-ྌက-ဪဿၐ-ၕၚ-ၝၡၥ-ၦၮ-ၰၵ-ႁႎႠ-ჅჇჍა-ჺჼ-ቈቊ-ቍቐ-ቖቘቚ-ቝበ-ኈኊ-ኍነ-ኰኲ-ኵኸ-ኾዀዂ-ዅወ-ዖዘ-ጐጒ-ጕጘ-ፚᎀ-ᎏᎠ-Ᏽᏸ-ᏽᐁ-ᙬᙯ-ᙿᚁ-ᚚᚠ-ᛪᛮ-ᛸᜀ-ᜌᜎ-ᜑᜠ-ᜱᝀ-ᝑᝠ-ᝬᝮ-ᝰក-ឳៗៜᠠ-ᡸᢀ-ᢨᢪᢰ-ᣵᤀ-ᤞᥐ-ᥭᥰ-ᥴᦀ-ᦫᦰ-ᧉᨀ-ᨖᨠ-ᩔᪧᬅ-ᬳᭅ-ᭋᮃ-ᮠᮮ-ᮯᮺ-ᯥᰀ-ᰣᱍ-ᱏᱚ-ᱽᲀ-ᲈᲐ-ᲺᲽ-Ჿᳩ-ᳬᳮ-ᳳᳵ-ᳶᳺᴀ-ᶿḀ-ἕἘ-Ἕἠ-ὅὈ-Ὅὐ-ὗὙὛὝὟ-ώᾀ-ᾴᾶ-ᾼιῂ-ῄῆ-ῌῐ-ΐῖ-Ίῠ-Ῥῲ-ῴῶ-ῼⁱⁿₐ-ₜℂℇℊ-ℓℕ℘-ℝℤΩℨK-ℹℼ-ℿⅅ-ⅉⅎⅠ-ↈⰀ-Ⱞⰰ-ⱞⱠ-ⳤⳫ-ⳮⳲ-ⳳⴀ-ⴥⴧⴭⴰ-ⵧⵯⶀ-ⶖⶠ-ⶦⶨ-ⶮⶰ-ⶶⶸ-ⶾⷀ-ⷆⷈ-ⷎⷐ-ⷖⷘ-ⷞ々-〇〡-〩〱-〵〸-〼ぁ-ゖゝ-ゟァ-ヺー-ヿㄅ-ㄯㄱ-ㆎㆠ-ㆿㇰ-ㇿ㐀-䶿一-鿼ꀀ-ꒌꓐ-ꓽꔀ-ꘌꘐ-ꘟꘪ-ꘫꙀ-ꙮꙿ-ꚝꚠ-ꛯꜗ-ꜟꜢ-ꞈꞋ-ꞿꟂ-ꟊꟵ-ꠁꠃ-ꠅꠇ-ꠊꠌ-ꠢꡀ-ꡳꢂ-ꢳꣲ-ꣷꣻꣽ-ꣾꤊ-ꤥꤰ-ꥆꥠ-ꥼꦄ-ꦲꧏꧠ-ꧤꧦ-ꧯꧺ-ꧾꨀ-ꨨꩀ-ꩂꩄ-ꩋꩠ-ꩶꩺꩾ-ꪯꪱꪵ-ꪶꪹ-ꪽꫀꫂꫛ-ꫝꫠ-ꫪꫲ-ꫴꬁ-ꬆꬉ-ꬎꬑ-ꬖꬠ-ꬦꬨ-ꬮꬰ-ꭚꭜ-ꭩꭰ-ꯢ가-힣ힰ-ퟆퟋ-ퟻ豈-舘並-龎ﬀ-ﬆﬓ-ﬗיִײַ-ﬨשׁ-זּטּ-לּמּנּ-סּףּ-פּצּ-ﮱﯓ-ﱝﱤ-ﴽﵐ-ﶏﶒ-ﷇﷰ-ﷹﹱﹳﹷﹹﹻﹽﹿ-ﻼＡ-Ｚａ-ｚｦ-ﾝﾠ-ﾾￂ-ￇￊ-ￏￒ-ￗￚ-ￜ-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------][0-9A-Z_a-zªµ·ºÀ-ÖØ-öø-ˁˆ-ˑˠ-ˤˬˮ̀-ʹͶ-ͷͻ-ͽͿΆ-ΊΌΎ-ΡΣ-ϵϷ-ҁ҃-҇Ҋ-ԯԱ-Ֆՙՠ-ֈ֑-ֽֿׁ-ׂׄ-ׇׅא-תׯ-ײؐ-ؚؠ-٩ٮ-ۓە-ۜ۟-۪ۨ-ۼۿܐ-݊ݍ-ޱ߀-ߵߺ߽ࠀ-࠭ࡀ-࡛ࡠ-ࡪࢠ-ࢴࢶ-ࣇ࣓-ࣣ࣡-ॣ०-९ॱ-ঃঅ-ঌএ-ঐও-নপ-রলশ-হ়-ৄে-ৈো-ৎৗড়-ঢ়য়-ৣ০-ৱৼ৾ਁ-ਃਅ-ਊਏ-ਐਓ-ਨਪ-ਰਲ-ਲ਼ਵ-ਸ਼ਸ-ਹ਼ਾ-ੂੇ-ੈੋ-੍ੑਖ਼-ੜਫ਼੦-ੵઁ-ઃઅ-ઍએ-ઑઓ-નપ-રલ-ળવ-હ઼-ૅે-ૉો-્ૐૠ-ૣ૦-૯ૹ-૿ଁ-ଃଅ-ଌଏ-ଐଓ-ନପ-ରଲ-ଳଵ-ହ଼-ୄେ-ୈୋ-୍୕-ୗଡ଼-ଢ଼ୟ-ୣ୦-୯ୱஂ-ஃஅ-ஊஎ-ஐஒ-கங-சஜஞ-டண-தந-பம-ஹா-ூெ-ைொ-்ௐௗ௦-௯ఀ-ఌఎ-ఐఒ-నప-హఽ-ౄె-ైొ-్ౕ-ౖౘ-ౚౠ-ౣ౦-౯ಀ-ಃಅ-ಌಎ-ಐಒ-ನಪ-ಳವ-ಹ಼-ೄೆ-ೈೊ-್ೕ-ೖೞೠ-ೣ೦-೯ೱ-ೲഀ-ഌഎ-ഐഒ-ൄെ-ൈൊ-ൎൔ-ൗൟ-ൣ൦-൯ൺ-ൿඁ-ඃඅ-ඖක-නඳ-රලව-ෆ්ා-ුූෘ-ෟ෦-෯ෲ-ෳก-ฺเ-๎๐-๙ກ-ຂຄຆ-ຊຌ-ຣລວ-ຽເ-ໄໆ່-ໍ໐-໙ໜ-ໟༀ༘-༙༠-༩༹༵༷༾-ཇཉ-ཬཱ-྄྆-ྗྙ-ྼ࿆က-၉ၐ-ႝႠ-ჅჇჍა-ჺჼ-ቈቊ-ቍቐ-ቖቘቚ-ቝበ-ኈኊ-ኍነ-ኰኲ-ኵኸ-ኾዀዂ-ዅወ-ዖዘ-ጐጒ-ጕጘ-ፚ፝-፟፩-፱ᎀ-ᎏᎠ-Ᏽᏸ-ᏽᐁ-ᙬᙯ-ᙿᚁ-ᚚᚠ-ᛪᛮ-ᛸᜀ-ᜌᜎ-᜔ᜠ-᜴ᝀ-ᝓᝠ-ᝬᝮ-ᝰᝲ-ᝳក-៓ៗៜ-៝០-៩᠋-᠍᠐-᠙ᠠ-ᡸᢀ-ᢪᢰ-ᣵᤀ-ᤞᤠ-ᤫᤰ-᤻᥆-ᥭᥰ-ᥴᦀ-ᦫᦰ-ᧉ᧐-᧚ᨀ-ᨛᨠ-ᩞ᩠-᩿᩼-᪉᪐-᪙ᪧ᪰-᪽ᪿ-ᫀᬀ-ᭋ᭐-᭙᭫-᭳ᮀ-᯳ᰀ-᰷᱀-᱉ᱍ-ᱽᲀ-ᲈᲐ-ᲺᲽ-Ჿ᳐-᳔᳒-ᳺᴀ-᷹᷻-ἕἘ-Ἕἠ-ὅὈ-Ὅὐ-ὗὙὛὝὟ-ώᾀ-ᾴᾶ-ᾼιῂ-ῄῆ-ῌῐ-ΐῖ-Ίῠ-Ῥῲ-ῴῶ-ῼ‿-⁀⁔ⁱⁿₐ-ₜ⃐-⃥⃜⃡-⃰ℂℇℊ-ℓℕ℘-ℝℤΩℨK-ℹℼ-ℿⅅ-ⅉⅎⅠ-ↈⰀ-Ⱞⰰ-ⱞⱠ-ⳤⳫ-ⳳⴀ-ⴥⴧⴭⴰ-ⵧⵯ⵿-ⶖⶠ-ⶦⶨ-ⶮⶰ-ⶶⶸ-ⶾⷀ-ⷆⷈ-ⷎⷐ-ⷖⷘ-ⷞⷠ-ⷿ々-〇〡-〯〱-〵〸-〼ぁ-ゖ゙-゚ゝ-ゟァ-ヺー-ヿㄅ-ㄯㄱ-ㆎㆠ-ㆿㇰ-ㇿ㐀-䶿一-鿼ꀀ-ꒌꓐ-ꓽꔀ-ꘌꘐ-ꘫꙀ-꙯ꙴ-꙽ꙿ-꛱ꜗ-ꜟꜢ-ꞈꞋ-ꞿꟂ-ꟊꟵ-ꠧ꠬ꡀ-ꡳꢀ-ꣅ꣐-꣙꣠-ꣷꣻꣽ-꤭ꤰ-꥓ꥠ-ꥼꦀ-꧀ꧏ-꧙ꧠ-ꧾꨀ-ꨶꩀ-ꩍ꩐-꩙ꩠ-ꩶꩺ-ꫂꫛ-ꫝꫠ-ꫯꫲ-꫶ꬁ-ꬆꬉ-ꬎꬑ-ꬖꬠ-ꬦꬨ-ꬮꬰ-ꭚꭜ-ꭩꭰ-ꯪ꯬-꯭꯰-꯹가-힣ힰ-ퟆퟋ-ퟻ豈-舘並-龎ﬀ-ﬆﬓ-ﬗיִ-ﬨשׁ-זּטּ-לּמּנּ-סּףּ-פּצּ-ﮱﯓ-ﱝﱤ-ﴽﵐ-ﶏﶒ-ﷇﷰ-ﷹ︀-️︠-︯︳-︴﹍-﹏ﹱﹳﹷﹹﹻﹽﹿ-ﻼ０-９Ａ-Ｚ＿ａ-ｚｦ-ﾾￂ-ￇￊ-ￏￒ-ￗￚ-ￜ-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]*"


def chars():
    for i in itertools.count():
        try:
            yield chr(i)
        except ValueError:
            break


def make_full_pattern():
    def make_pattern(is_valid):
        pattern = ""

        for is_identifier, group in itertools.groupby(chars(), is_valid):
            if is_identifier:
                group = list(group)
                if len(group) == 1:
                    pattern += group[0]
                else:
                    pattern += group[0] + "-" + group[-1]

        return "[" + pattern + "]"

    return make_pattern(str.isidentifier) + make_pattern(lambda c: ("x" + c).isidentifier()) + "*"


def test_pattern():
    assert full_pattern == make_full_pattern()
    identifier_regex = re.compile(full_pattern)

    for char in chars():
        for string in [char, "x" + char]:
            assert bool(identifier_regex.fullmatch(string)) == string.isidentifier()


test_pattern()
```