# Pythonically check if a variable name is valid

Tags: python

tldr; see the final line; the rest is just preamble.

---

I am developing a test harness, which parses user scripts and generates a Python script which it then runs. The idea is for non-techie folks to be able to write high-level test scripts.

I have introduced the idea of variables, so a user can use the `LET` keyword in his script. E.g. `LET X = 42`, which I simply expand to `X = 42`. They can then use X later in their scripts - `RELEASE CONNECTION X`

But what if someone writes `LET 2 = 3`? That's going to generate invalid Python.

If I have that `X` in a variable `variableName`, then how can I check whether `variableName` is a valid Python variable?

Comment: On the side: Why do you think "LET X = 42" is easier for "non-techie folks" than "X = 42"?

Comment: One option is to use a regex. See [Regular expression to confirm whether a string is a valid identifier in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5474008/4014959)

Comment: @PM2Ring - Note that that's for Python 2. It's less simple for [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) (also see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/) and [here](http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/table-3131.html).

Comment: @timgeb the answer to that is quite Basic :-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In Python 3 you can use [`str.isidentifier()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=identifier#str.isidentifier) to test whether a given string is a valid Python identifier/name.

```
>>> 'X'.isidentifier()
True
>>> 'X123'.isidentifier()
True
>>> '2'.isidentifier()
False
>>> 'while'.isidentifier()
True
```

The last example shows that you should also check whether the variable name clashes with a Python keyword:

```
>>> from keyword import iskeyword
>>> iskeyword('X')
False
>>> iskeyword('while')
True
```

So you could put that together in a function:

```
from keyword import iskeyword

def is_valid_variable_name(name):
    return name.isidentifier() and not iskeyword(name)
```

---

Another option, which works in Python 2 and 3, is to use the `ast` module:

```
from ast import parse

def is_valid_variable_name(name):
    try:
        parse('{} = None'.format(name))
        return True
    except SyntaxError, ValueError, TypeError:
        return False

>>> is_valid_variable_name('X')
True
>>> is_valid_variable_name('123')
False
>>> is_valid_variable_name('for')
False
>>> is_valid_variable_name('')
False
>>> is_valid_variable_name(42)
False
```

This will parse the assignment statement without actually executing it. It will pick up invalid identifiers as well as attempts to assign to a keyword. In the above code `None` is an arbitrary value to assign to the given name - it could be any valid expression for the RHS.

Comment: `compile('{} = None'.format(name), "<string>", "exec")`  and `return True`  after should be enough

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Thanks.  Either works and `ast.parse()`  calls `compile()` anyway. I think that it's a little cleaner with `ast.parse()` because there are fewer arguments, although it does require an import.

Comment: For what it's worth, `is_valid_variable_name('a = b')`, `is_valid_variable_name('[]')`, `is_valid_variable_name('*a')` will all return `True`.

Comment: @vaultah: it's worth a great deal and thanks for finding the flaw in my solution. Worth also noting that this problem only affects the `ast.parse()` solution. AFAIK the first solution still works as expected.

Comment: @mhawke: yes, the first solution should work fine. Sorry, I should have mentioned that

Comment: `is_valid_variable_name("a      +") is True` @vultah

Comment: Maybe try parsing a `def` or `lambda` with the tested string as a parameter name, instead of parsing a variable assignment. A lot of these edge cases which parse validly for `{} = None` should get rejected for something like `lambda {}=None: {}`.

Comment: I think there is no *robust and universal* way with `ast.parse`... the `,` character is particularly tricky, as it survives the switch from an assignment to a function parameter. Seems like if you want to be portable, there's no way around either checking the string manually for certain characters, or maybe doing a loop where you `parse` not only `name` but also all prefix substrings `name[:1]` to `name[:-1]`.

Comment: Although... I think we *do* rule out all unsafe-to-evaluate inputs that are valid Python <=2 if we try to `parse('lambda {0}=0: {0}'.format(name))`. Because the only unsafe thing that can validly parse in the first substitution is a default argument assignment, such as in `a=unsafe(),b`, but then the `=` would be an invalid assignment statement in the second substitution, which must be an expression because it's a `lambda` body. (However I haven't ruled out for sure if any Python >=3.* syntax adds something exploitable to the picture... for example `:` to introduce evaluated annotations.)

Comment: So in principle a portable approach might be to use `str.isidentifier(name) and not iskeyword(name)` if the former is available, otherwise fall back to a `parse` and then if that succeeds, you know it's safe to evaluate/execute to rule out the remaining edge-cases such as `a,b` (although if you know all the edge-cases that get through the lambda parse, then maybe it's better to just manually check for those cases).

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: this is wrong and implementation dependent - see comments.

Just have Python do its own check by making a dictionary with the variable holding the name as the key and splatting it as keyword arguments:

```
def _dummy_function(**kwargs):
    pass

def is_valid_variable_name(name):
    try:
        _dummy_function(**{name: None})
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

Notably, `TypeError` is consistently raised whenever a `dict` splats into keyword arguments but has a key which isn't a valid function argument, **and** whenever a `dict` literal is being constructed with an invalid key, so this will work correctly on *anything* you pass to it.

Comment: `**kwargs` can contain non-valid variable names. E.g. `is_valid_variable_name('[]')` returned True. I was not able to find any string, where this function returns False. Might be different in python 2.

Comment: @ChristophBöddeker wild. I have strong memories of this working to reject arguments. But at least on 3.10 it behaves as you describe.

Comment: I found [a Python mailing list discussion](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/GMSIA7ACABIHLPU7AXRIONXSSAEFKSFH/) which indicates this was always the case. So I guess I was just wrong and didn't properly test it with strings. (It does reject non-strings, but that's not what this question is about.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the exact same naming syntax as python itself.
Would rather go for a simple regexp like:

```
\w+
```

to make sure it's something alphanumeric, and then add a prefix to keep away from python's own syntax. So the non-techie user's declaration:

```
LET return = 12
```

should probably become after your parsing:

```
userspace_return = 12
or
userspace['return'] = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, as above, you can simply use [`str.isidentifier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier). But in Python 2, this does not exist.

The [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tokenize.html#str.isidentifier) module has a regex for names (identifiers): [`tokenize.Name`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/tokenize.py#L52). But I couldn't find any documentation for it, so it may not be available everywhere. It is simply `r'[a-zA-Z_]\w*'`. A single `$` after it will let you test strings with `re.match`.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) say that an identifier is defined by this grammar:

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

Which is equivalent to the regex above. But we should still import `tokenize.Name` in case this ever changes. (Which is very unlikely, but maybe in older versions of Python it was different?)

And to filter out keywords, like `pass`, `def` and `return`, use `keyword.iskeyword`. There is one caveat: `None` is not a keyword in Python 2, but still can't be assigned to. (`keyword.iskeyword('None')` in Python 2 is `False`).

So:

```
import keyword

if hasattr(str, 'isidentifier'):
    _isidentifier = str.isidentifier
else:
    import re
    _fallback_pattern = '[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    try:
        import tokenize
    except ImportError:
        _isidentifier = re.compile(_fallback_pattern + '$').match
    else:
        _isidentifier = re.compile(
            getattr(tokenize, 'Name', _fallback_pattern) + '$'
        ).match

    del _fallback_pattern


def isname(s):
    return bool(_isidentifier(s)) and not keyword.iskeyword(s) and s != 'None'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use exceptions handling and catch actually `NameError` and `SyntaxError`. Test it inside `try/except` block and inform user if there is some invalid input.

Comment: The this is that I want to validate when I am generating the code. Now when it is run, which could be much later.

Comment: Aha, I could test it before generating the code! Well done! Thanks.

Comment: A `SyntaxError` will prevent the script from running. The only way (AFAIK) to actually catch a `SyntaxError` is if you `import` a Python file that contains a syntax error.

Comment: @timgeb: Ah, of course. I wasn't thinking about `eval` or `exec`, since I tend to avoid using them, especially on arbitrary input from "non-techie folks". :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try a test assignment and see if it raises a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> 2fg = 5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    2fg = 5
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This assumes you are able to evaluate the name in the Python interpreter, and is unsafe for programmatic checking in the general case (`import os; os.replace(malicious_file, important_file); foo` can have `= 5` appended to it and still execute just fine).